# Need explanation for this code, ajax upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function saveimage(){
      if($('#abc').val() != ''){
        var input = document.getElementById("abc");
        file = input.files[0];
          if(file != undefined){
            formData= new FormData();
              if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
                formData.append("image", file);
                $.ajax({
                  url: "phpupload.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: formData,
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  success: function(data){
                    //no nothing as of now.
                  }
                });
              }else{
                alert('Not a valid image!');
              }
          }else{
            alert('Image related error, please refresh and try again!');
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

This works for me, but i can't understand exactly what its doing. Particularly, these are my questions:

1. Line 5 `file = input.files[0];` From where does the files array appear. I never initialised it.
2. Since its an array, and i am calling file[0], could i add more destinations to this array, to upload more than one file at a time?
3. Line 7 `formData= new FormData();` What does formData do? In what ways can it be used?
4. Line 8 `if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/))` this one line seems to filter uploaded file types. How does this work? Any reference to this would be greatly helpful.
5. Line 9 `formData.append("image", file);` I have no idea what this is for.
6. Line 13 `data: formData,` Could i send additional post variables along with formData to my php file?
7. Lastly Line 16 `success: function(data){` success seems like a keyword, is there one for failure? What determines success or failure? Do i have to return false by my php file?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. it appears on line 4 when its retrieved from element `#abc` 2. yes 3. creates a `formData` object. 4. `!!` converts the output of this comparison to a boolean value. if the file type meta info doesnt match the regex, `-1` is returned and then is converted to false. this is one very sloppy line of code that will lead to almost certain bugs. 5. that appends the binary file data to the form upload object. 6. this declares that the data to be sent in the request is `Formdata` 7. thats the success callback for completion of the upload request

Comment: Thanks. so 5. binary data getting appended. Basically whats happening is that the file is getting converted to 1s and 0s and then getting appended to the formData object. What happens if you don't do it? Shouldn't this happen by default? Is formData used in other places where one does not need to attach binary data?

Comment: Actually it gets converted to a character stream (e.g. base 64 encoding) as all POST data is just text. Use a network tool to view the data posted (e.g. Fiddler2),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you had posted the HTML too you would have noted it is a `file` input. That has a readonly `files` array containing information about the file(s) selected for uploads (including a stream of the files contents).
2. Multiple file support is down to the browser (e.g. HTML5 or not). There are third party controls that will allow multiple file upload on older browsers (e.g. uploadify), but they basically split the process into multiple upload posts themselves.
3. `formData` is simply an object that gets converted to name/value pairs for shipping to the server as part of the Ajax POST call.
4. `if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/))` is just testing the filetype with a "regular expression". Google for "regex". `!!` just converts a number (zero or non-zero) to a boolean value of true/false.
5. `formData.append("image", file);` simply adds the file stream as a named property called `image` to the uploaded data. This is the same as doing something like:

   `formData.image = file;`

but the internal storage details are hidden from you (and you do not care).

6. Yes, you can add other values to the data sent. Just give them new names and add them to the formData object the same way:

   `formData.append("some property", someValue);`
7. `success` is an ajax callback property that expects a function. It is called if the Ajax call returns from the server with no error. Else it calls an `error` callback.

Note:

The first part of the code is redundantly getting the input element in two ways. The first few lines could also be written as:

```
var input = $("#abc");              // get the input element as a jQuery element
if(input.val() != ''){              // if it has a value...
     var file = input[0].files[0];  // Get the file from the first DOM element
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be the syntax to send additional data with formData? `{data: formData, var: 'postdata'}` Is this good?

Comment: Also, could you explain `formData.append("image", file);` in a little detail. I can't understand your answer.

Comment: @user3324298: Updated both those areas based on your comments. Let me know if I need to explain any points more clearly (it was a lot to type off the top of my head) :)

Comment: No more explanation required for the initial questions. This is great. But one follow-up question, about adding the file stream to the formData object. The internals are hidden as its binary stuff right. Shouldn't this happen by default? Any file that a user uploads, it will need to be converted to binary, why have this additional step? Basically what i am asking is, is formData used only in uploads or could i create a formData object for any ajax call? I never use the standard `$.ajax{}` method. Always used the `$.get` and `$.post`. In those, i never had to use formData.

Comment: Yeah, ok i saw your comment above. Thanks!